# Is there any better way we can loop through tables other than this?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CUSTOMER USERID 
---------------
tom      tom22
Jerry    Jerry092
tom      tom22
```

Assume I have a table like above, I have a lot of additional columns in this table.

Now for each distinct CUSTOMER, USER ID combo, I have to enter certain details from this table to another table.

Basically I have duplicate values in the main table and I only want to take distinct item and then insert some details of that item to another table.

I have written a query like below

```
FOR S IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER, USERID 
    FROM maintable
) LOOP INSERT INTO anothertable (ID, NAME, AGE, PIN)
           SELECT
               K.USERID, K.CUSTOMER, K.AGE, K.PIN 
           FROM
               maintable K
           WHERE
               s.CUSTOMER = K.customer
               AND s.USERID = K.USERID;
END LOOP;
```

Is there any better way I can write it ?

Comment: What is the code expected to do?

Comment: select distinct doesn't help, the INSERT SELECT will still insert every row.

Comment: It should insert some values from main table to another table (distinct selection of items from the maintable)

Comment: But it doesn't. You will have all rows (at least as long there are no null values involved.)

Comment: A [mcve] will make things much clearer. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Ya, but i want to insert only distinct items from the maintable. So that is why i am selecting distinct items from maintable first and loop through each item and insert in to anothertable.

Comment: The distinct values doesn't matter, the SELECT will still return all rows.

Comment: Ohh, is there any way we can resolve it  ? Basically i have duplicate values in the main table and I  only want to take distinct item and then insert some details of that item to another table.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are *slow* as you process row-by-row.

To "simulate" your code (without a loop), you could rewrite it to

```
insert into anothertable (id, name, age, pin)
select k.userid, k.customer, k.age, k.pin
from maintable k join (select distinct customer, userid
                       from maintable
                      ) a on a.customer = k.customer
                         and a.userid = k.userid;
```

but it would still insert as many rows as there are in the `maintable` as you're joining distinct `(customer, userid)` combination to **every** row in `maintable` once again. It should, though, be *faster* than your code.

---

If you want to have a distinct set of `(customer, userid)` in `anothertable`, then you'll have to pick only one `age` and `pin` column value. Which one? I don't know, but it could be e.g. `MAX` of them, such as

```
insert into anothertable (id, name, age, pin)
select userid, customer, max(age), max(pin)
from maintable
group by userid, customer;
```

If that's still not what you want, perhaps you should provide test case - current data set in `maintable` and desired result in `anothertable`.